# Callback not called if it is a class method

Tags: python, python-2.7

Python newbie question: the callback method `handlePackets` never gets called if it is a class method. If it is not in a class it works fine. What can I do?

```
class Receiver:

    def __enter__(self):
        self.serial_port = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 115200)
        self.xbee = ZigBee(self.serial_port, escaped=True,    callback=self.handlePackets)
        Logger.info('Receiver: enter')
        return self

    def __exit__(self ,type, value, traceback):
        Logger.info('Receiver: exit')
        self.serial_port.close()

    def handlePackets(data):
        Logger.info('Receiver: packet incoming')
```

Comment: Are you trying to use it as a context manager? Then those should be `__enter__` and `__exit__`. Otherwise, what code is calling `enter`?

Comment: They are. Corrected in post.

Comment: I guess its possible that there is a problem with old-style classes. In python 2.7, declare the class `class Receiver(object):`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can bet it is because, whatever is calling your callback from within `ZigBee` is failing silently. The interpreter calls your function with 2 parameters, but as you have defined it -- it takes only one.

```
def handlePackets(self, data):
                 #^^^^
```

Comment: When I make handlePackets global it runs just fine.

Comment: Yes, that is *probably* because when you have `handlePackets` callback passed as `self.handlePacket`, you are required to pass in `self` in the first parameter.

Comment: @tdelaney: Nope. Please run a test code yourself to see what happens. Gist: when you say: `self.handlePacket`, you are binding the first parameter to `self` or the instance of the class.  Then for the second time when you call it with one parameter, you it gets bound to the second parameter. So you do need 2 parameters.